# styling an angular component

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm still very new to angular. I've created a component named header via the cli. I have added the html for the navbar i want to use. I also have some css i want to add. I put it in the scss file but it doesnt seem to be working.
here's my css:

```
html,
body,
header,
.view {
    height: 100%;
}
/* Navigation*/

.navbar {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.top-nav-collapse {
    background-color: #4285F4;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar {
        background-color: #4285F4;
    }
}
/*Intro*/
.view {
    background: url("https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/12-col/img%20(54).jpg")no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

here's my html:

```
<navbar SideClass="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-dark introZindex fixed-top">
    <logo>
        <a class="logo navbar-brand">Navbar</a>
    </logo>
    <links>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link">Pricing</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav-flex-icons">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </links>
</navbar>
<!-- Main -->
<div class="view hm-black-strong">
    <div class="full-bg-img flex-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="white-text text-center wow fadeInUp">
                <h2>This Navbar is fixed and transparent</h2>
                <br>
                <h5>It will always stay visible on the top, even when you scroll down</h5>
                <br>
                <p>Full page intro with background image will be always displayed in full screen mode, regardless of device </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.Main -->
<main class="text-center py-5 mt-3">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p align="justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

here is the ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

here is my app.module.ts file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { MDBBootstrapModule } from './typescripts/angular-bootstrap-md/free';
import { MDBBootstrapModulePro } from './typescripts/angular-bootstrap-md/pro';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
    MDBBootstrapModulePro.forRoot(),
    // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=en#key
    // AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
    //   apiKey: 'google_maps_api_key'
    // })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Can anyone give me advice as to what I'm doing wrong here? the only thing in my app.component.html is  which is the tag for the above mentioned component.

Comment: Can you show the code for the component itself? Probably called header.ts

Comment: Kindly provide the .ts code as well.

Comment: yes, ill add it to the original post

Comment: maybe its because of your css problem not angular problem, check it with `background-color: black !important` term in `.view` css, if this new style works, it's your css problem

Comment: it made no difference @HasanBeheshti

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't add color to your navbar and that's the only reason why u don't see styles. It's enough if you add `bg-primary` class (or any other with the color you prefer) to your `SideClass`.

Comment: Thank you Adrian, that fixed it! The code needs to be updated on the MDB site. It currently doesn't provide that: http://imgur.com/a/HjaI9

Answer (score 1):

Update

Just see `navbar` tag on your html template. Did you declare (in module) and import it?

---

> I put it in the `scss` file

I guess you didn't config for styling extension.

Please check `angular-cli.json` and add these lines

```
"defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss"
}
```

Or run the command

```
ng set defaults.styleExt scss
```

Then please ensure that you link correct location to your styling file.

Comment: i ran the `ng set defaults.styleExt scss` from the command line and am still getting the same results

Comment: its not relevant, because you're not using special scss function in your scss file, so its not helping

Comment: @YasinShuman: But what is `not working` as you said? What is your expectation and what you get?
@HasanBeheshti: I just get that, even if you don't use any special scss features, it cannot load the style file then nothing happen.

Comment: @ManhLe none of the styling i have in the scss file is working. this is what it looks like http://imgur.com/a/RT540

Comment: Just see `navbar` tag on your html template. Did you declare (in module) and import it?

Comment: @ManhLe I'm going to update the original post with a copy of my app.module.ts I think everything is imported, would you mind taking a look?

Comment: I see you use MDBootstrap lib, not sure it or another (https://mdbootstrap.com/angular/5min-quickstart/).
But let see in `step 8` and make sure you added in `angular-cli.json`

Comment: @ManhLe hi, i used their template they provide instead of creating the whole project from scratch. they provided it for the paid edition. To be safe, i added that line to the angular-cli.json file anyway and saved all and refreshed and there was no change.

Comment: Did you check Step 11: add @imports to styles.scss: @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
It's quite hard to find the reason cause it not free.
I suggest you can follow the `Getting started`, with free version to see it work or not. Its take time, but can compare what you miss in your product.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got in touch with the MDBootstrap guys and found there was a missing helper class on the navbar in the html file. Once i added bg-primary it worked. So it looked like this: `<navbar SideClass="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-dark introZindex fixed-top bg-primary">`

Answer (score -1):

In your `app.component.ts` file make sure  `@Component({})` contains `StylesUrls[]` or `Styles[]`. If you have created App.component using Cli then there would be `StylesUrls['app.component.css']`.

So open your app.component.css file and write all the CSS code there to style your app.component.html.

If you are using `styles: []` define all the styling between ['styling goes here'].

Because you have a lot of styling so use stylingUrls['directory/filename.css'].

**Update:**

If you are following this procedure and still not working. Then restart your virtual server. More info about this here: ["Port 4200 is already in use" when running the ng serve command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091735/port-4200-is-already-in-use-when-running-the-ng-serve-command)

Comment: Hi, and thanks for responding! So, are you saying i should put all my styling for the header component in the app.component.css file as well? it doesnt go in the header.component.scss file? thats the one listed in the ts file for the header component im trying to style.