# Angular-cli port 4200 in use and not closing after exiting the process

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular5

This issue started happening to me about 1 month ago probably after updating my angular version to v5.2.5 from 5.0.

In the past, when I wrote the command `ng serve` and closed the process with Ctrl + C, the listener on that port stopped as well.

Now, when doing the same process, the process is closed successfully, but when trying to run it again, it keeps telling me that the port is in use.

While executing the command lsof -i:4200 I can clearly see that it keeps the listener even after terminating the process.

Is there a way to fix this? Is it an issue with this version of angular5?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Port 4200 is already in use" when running the ng serve command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091735/port-4200-is-already-in-use-when-running-the-ng-serve-command), + github issue 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4895

Comment: The first stackoverflow link only discussed how to close the already running port without addressing the real issue. From the second one, I tried running the commands rm -rf node_modules, npm i, and it fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

`rm -rf node_modules
npm i`

Fixed the problem.

Comment: Bit odd, but yes, removing node_modules and installing them worked.