# "port 4200 already in use" error, inspite it is not being used

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am starting up with a angular project. While running ng-serve `port 4200 already in use` error comes up. I have tried all the trivial solutions. `netstat` does not show up any process running on `127.0.0.1:4200`. Also tried with `--port` command to change the default port, unfortunately dint work for any entered ports (tried it thrice with different port numbers). Have visited almost all the answers in here, none helped. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Port 4200 is already in use" when running the ng serve command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091735/port-4200-is-already-in-use-when-running-the-ng-serve-command)

Comment: as in? can you please elaborate?
Because I am getting same error for all the entered ports, be it `4201` or `3000`

Comment: As already mentioned in the question itself, I'd been through the answer in above post, but none helped.

Comment: try a `lsof -i:4200` and see what comes.

Comment: @YuvrajJaiswal I am using Windows machine, so unable to run above command. If it intents to kill the process running on this port or fetch the pid of the process running on this port, then I have tried other methods to do so on windows, hence I am sure that none of the process is running on this port.

Comment: @luckysadhwani Did you finally solve this issue and how ?

Answer (score 1):

try this
`ng serve --port 0`

It will listen on some unassigned port.

Answer (score 0):

that may be becouse the server is still runing, if you code in Visual Studio Code open the Promp in the node terminal press Ctrl+C, ll ask you if u want to finish, say Yes, and then try to run de ng serve again.

in Angular the server is placed in http://localhost:4200/, not in 127.0.0.1

You can open multiple serve with "ng serve --port 3300" change de number as you wish

Sry for my bad english

Comment: If the server is still running and not killed completely, it should have shown me in the results on netstat.

Answer (score 0):

in that case use angular command-

> ```
> ng serve --port 4201
> ```

you've to change the port number.