# Port -4200 is being in used in angular 7 application

Tags: macos, angular7

I have an angular 7 application which I'm developing on a MAC environment. The thing is when I run **ng serve** for the first time it works fine. But when I press **Ctrl + Z** and again run **ng serve**, it gives the following error:

```
 Port 4200 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port.
```

This did not used to happen in windows environment. Do I have to do some extra step to get rid of this error? I want to run on the same port no.

Comment: I suggest adding a tag about mac or something relevant to the apple ecosystem. As this could be caused due to how mac handles ports.

Comment: Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091735/port-4200-is-already-in-use-when-running-the-ng-serve-command)., it's explained what to do for different system OS.

Comment: yeah the link provided by @Ardit helped me, just refer the section https://stackoverflow.com/a/40463142/9855057 of the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was to terminate the current execution of project using  **Ctrl + C** ***on mac*** which ultimately kills the port. Again we can start the project using ng serve without using any port number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:4200)
```