# ng serve refuses to use any port

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular application that refuses to run.  It keeps saying `Port 1234 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port.`, which is crap because it says that about any port number I throw in.  I know these ports aren't in use because I'm not using them.  If I run something like `live-server`, it runs fine on port 3000.  I shut it down and tell `ng serve` to use port 3000, it then acts like port 3000 is in use.

I've rebooted my macbook, I've tried commands like `lsof -t -i tcp:80 -s tcp:listen | sudo xargs kill` and nothing has been any help.

I have a different Angular App in another directory that works fine when I run `ng serve` but again, that one's not running at the moment and shouldn't be blocking this particular app I'm trying to work on.

I've visited ["Port 4200 is already in use" when running the ng serve command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091735/port-4200-is-already-in-use-when-running-the-ng-serve-command) and none of the solutions there seemed to have worked.

I'm pretty sure there aren't any ports other than the reserved ones in use at the moment.  If I open one of my React projects and run `npm run start` it happily opens up on port 3000, whereas if I try 3000, or any other port number with Angular, it fails.  So it's not an issue of ports being in use by other processes.

This is Angular CLI 6.1.10

Comment: Just posted : https://stackoverflow.com/q/57562890/5468463

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is [an issue with portfinder](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15369). I was able to get it working by explicitly declaring the version of portfinder in my devDependencies of my package.json.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "6.1.3",
    "portfinder": "1.0.20",
}
```